# Wordpress wp-admin not working after the Wordpress was migrated to another server for php 7.4

Tags: php, wordpress, server, backend, wp-admin

I changed (via the hosting company) the server of a Wordpress Website - in order to upgrade an PHP 7.4. The Website was on an old version of wordpress and it was running on php 5.6.

After Migration - i cannot acces the wp-admin page.

website:   **[www.naturalactivplant.ro](http://www.naturalactivplant.ro)**  (the website frontend is working OK)

wp-admin link:   **[www.naturalactivplant.ro/naturvit/](http://www.naturalactivplant.ro/naturvit/)**    << after entering the credentials - seems that the page doesnot exists.  it redirects here >> **naturalactivplant.ro/wp-admin/**   with the message>  This page isn't working.

Comment: You are using an old WordPress version

Comment: Try running on php 7.0 update your WP then change php to 7.4 or 8. Another option is to reinstall wp

Comment: Check with debugging on true with `wp-config.php` file `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`

Comment: I changed from false to true.. seems like some plugins are not ok. Or? Any help?

Comment: @KrupalPanchal any suggestions?

Comment: Yes you can check with deactivating each plugin turn by turn, so you can get an idea which plugin causes the issue.

Comment: What exactly did you do, to make the admin login available under `/naturvit/` in the first place? What does the error log have to say about the reason for the 500 you are getting when `/wp-admin/` is accessed?

Comment: To change under /naturvit/   i used a plugin who worked very good. No problem with the plugin.

Comment: @CBroe - debuging mode true>    www.naturalactivplant.ro

Comment: @CBroe 

http://naturalactivplant.ro/wp-admin/  

See here the error log.

Comment: Sounds like you should see to it that you get the `revslider` plugin updated to a current version first of all.

Comment: But how can I Update a Plugin - if I cannot login in the Admin/dashboard? pls help

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED>>
Changed the PHP version back to 5.3 and increased the memory-limit size to 512 Mb.

Comment: PHP 5.3 is out of support since seven years, and should not be used anywhere